# How to remove undefined and create a new array Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var imagesList = [undefined x 1, cars.jpg, undefined x 1, boats.jpg];
```

How do I filter out the undefined? so I  can get it as follows:

```
var imagesShow = [cars.jpg, boats.jpg];
```

I have not found much documentation on getting rid of undefined in an array using javascript.

Comment: what means `undefined x 1`?

Comment: console.log of a sparse array.

Comment: When you use "delete" method for Javascript arrays, you get undefined x1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) as callback for truthy values.

```js
var imagesList = [undefined, 'cars.jpg', undefined, 'boats.jpg'],
    imagesShow = imagesList.filter(Boolean);
    
console.log(imagesShow);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `Array#filter`:

```js
var imagesList = [undefined, 'cars.jpg', undefined, 'boats.jpg'];

var result = imagesList.filter(function(v) {
  return v !== undefined;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the Array.filter function

```
var imagesShow = imagesList.filter(function (value) {
    return value != undefined;
};
```

Any array element that does not pass the check in the callback function above will be filtered out  - in this case, if the element is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`Array.Filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```js
 var imagesList = [undefined, 'cars.jpg', undefined, 'boats.jpg'];
    var result = imagesList.filter(function( element ) {
       return element !== undefined;
    });
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method with [ES6 Arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function expression.

```js
var imagesList = [undefined, "cars.jpg", undefined, "boats.jpg"];

var filteredList = imagesList.filter(item => { return item !== undefined });

console.log(filteredList);
```

Answer (score 0):

By displaying `undefined x 2`, your array clearly indicates that it's a sparse one which means you don't have any undefined items. You just don't have the keys to hold items to start with.

OK you may have and wish to keep proper `void 0` or `undefined` items (in which case all of the above solutions will fail) or a numeric value `0` or `null` object item (in which case the accepted answer will fail).

In order to convert a sparse array to dense form the [most efficient method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41907709/4543207) would be a `for in` loop (or `Object.keys()`).

So for sparse array looping it's best to use

```js
var res = [],
    a   = [];
a[1] = "cars.jpg";
a[5] = null;
a[999999] = "beauty.jpg";

// [undefined × 1, "cars.jpg", undefined × 3, null, undefined × 999993, "beauty.jpg"]

function dense(a){
  var r = [];
  for (i in a) r.push(a[i]);
  return r;
}

console.time("test");
res = dense(a);
console.timeEnd("test");
console.log(res);
```

Now lets compare the above code with an elegant filtering solution;

```js
var res = [],
    a   = [];
a[1] = "cars.jpg";
a[5] = null;
a[999999] = "beauty.jpg";

// [undefined × 1, "cars.jpg", undefined × 3, null, undefined × 999993, "beauty.jpg"]

console.time("test");
res = a.filter(Boolean);
console.timeEnd("test");
console.log(res);
```

So as you see `null` is disappeared and it is slower since it checks all non existing keys. However with `for in` loop keeping the falsey values or not is totally under your control.